# Smallest launch vehicle by dry mass

Tags: launch-vehicle, record

What is the smallest launch vehicle, by dry mass, to have delivered a payload to orbit?

I am guessing that this might be either a re-purposed sounding rocket or something from the high-end of the model rocketry space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Lambda 4S from Mark Adlers' answer has later been surpassed by another Japanese rocket, the [SS-520](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Series_(rocket_family)), which successfully delivered a 4kg payload to LEO in 2018.

The total mass of the vehicle is 2,600kg, which [with propellant subtracted](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2018/02/japanese-rocket-record-borbital-launch/) is 610kg of dry mass.

As you correctly guessed, it's indeed a repurposed sounding rocket.

Answer (score 10):

For dry mass, it appears to be [Vanguard](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanguard_(rocket)) with a launch mass of 10,050 kg, and a dry mass of 1536 kg.

At first I thought it was the [Japanese Lambda 4S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_4S) weighing in at a lower 9400 kg at launch.  However it's "dry" mass (mass with the solid propellant subtracted) [is 2408 kg](http://www.isas.jaxa.jp/e/enterp/rockets/vehicles/l-4s/index.shtml).

Comment: Scott Manley's [How Small Can You Make An Orbital Rocket?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1bZO16em2c)

Comment: not orbital yet, but I think that's the goal: [Momo-3 is Japan's first private rocket to reach space](https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2019/05/04/business/tech/momo-3-becomes-first-privately-developed-japanese-rocket-reach-outer-space/) and also https://youtu.be/oZiWWz2Z2VQ