# Smallest orbital rockets by height?

Tags: launch-vehicle, record

Which orbital rocket is the smallest in height (or length) that ever launched?

Would be nice to know the second and third place too.

Similar questions:

- [Smallest orbital rocket by diameter?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48183/smallest-orbital-rocket-by-diameter)
- [Smallest orbital rocket by mass](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17133/what-is-was-the-smallest-orbital-launch-system-by-total-mass)
- [Smallest launch vehicle by dry mass](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2043/smallest-launch-vehicle-by-dry-mass)
- [Smallest sounding rocket to reach space by height?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48151/smallest-sounding-rocket-to-reach-space-by-height)
- [Do you know a rocket for launching femto and pico satellites smaller than the SS-520?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/49542/do-you-know-a-rocket-for-launching-femto-and-pico-satellites-smaller-than-the-ss)
- [What are some small rocket engines?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/49716/what-are-some-small-rocket-engines)

Comment: SS-520 is also the answer to: [How small could an orbital rocket be?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18789/12102) and [Do launchers using only solid propellant exist?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26693/12102), and [Why isn't there a rocket to launch a single cubesat?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36261/12102), and [Is it possible to build a rocket with 2kg payload?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40612/12102)...

Comment: ...and [What is/was the smallest orbital launch system, by total mass?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17133/12102) and also see [If there “won't be” rockets to launch individual cubesats, then why did JAXA build exactly that? (SS-520-xx)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37909/12102).

Comment: Also interesting - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-lift_launch_vehicle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is as far as I can tell the [SS-520](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Series_(rocket_family)), placing a 4kg payload into LEO in 2018, with the total length of the launch vehicle being [9.54 meters](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2018/02/japanese-rocket-record-borbital-launch/).

If this record has not been surpassed after 2018, it still stands.

Comment: Lambda 4S - 16.5 m <> Pegasus - 16.9 m <> Jielong 1 - 19.5 m <> Long March 11 - 20.8 m <> Hyperbola-1 - 20.8 m <> Juno I - 21.2 m

Comment: Blue Whale 1 - 1.8 m <> Astra - 11.6 m <> Vector-R - 12 m

Comment: @JoeJobs Has Blue Whale 1 been launched yet?

Comment: No the second line has orbital rockets who didnt reach orbit yet

Comment: Black Arrow - 13 m <> Electron - 17 m <> Diamant - 18.95 m

Comment: Minotaur I - 19.21 m