# Smallest sounding rocket to reach space by height?

Tags: record, sounding-rocket

Which is the smallest sounding rocket to reach space (100 km)?
By height

Similar question:

[Smallest orbital rockets by height?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48148/smallest-orbital-rockets-by-height)

Comment: re quick (sub-1-day) acceptance: [ditto](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48148/smallest-orbital-rockets-by-height#comment155558_48148)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of "reaching space", in contrast to orbit is a bit arbitrary. The [Kármán line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line) of 100km is often used.

An amateur rocket launch, but the USC rocket team [reached 103.6km with their Traveler IV](http://www.uscrpl.com/traveler-iv). They list their rocket as 13 foot tall, or around 4 metres.

That gives an upper bound.

If you consider 72km sufficient, the [Black Brant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Brant_(rocket)) VI and VII rockets can reach that altitude with a 2.80m launch vehicle.