# Smallest orbital rocket by diameter?

Tags: launch-vehicle, record

Which orbital rocket has the smallest diameter?

Without fins.

Related question:

- [Smallest orbital rockets by height?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48148/smallest-orbital-rockets-by-height)
- [Smallest orbital rocket by mass](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17133/what-is-was-the-smallest-orbital-launch-system-by-total-mass)
- [Smallest launch vehicle by dry mass](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2043/smallest-launch-vehicle-by-dry-mass)

Comment: I'm betting it's Vanguard...or one of those wacky unguided early Japanese rockets

Comment: With or without fins?

Comment: Without fins better

Comment: It's probably the SS-520 again at 0.52 m diameter

Comment: Yeah, I'd put my money on the SS-520, but I'd have to do some research.  Some of the rockets under design, but not yet launched may be even smaller.