# Most noodle-like (highest aspect ratio) orbital launch vehicle ever?

Tags: launch, history, launch-vehicle, record

- [Just how much can tall skinny rockets bend? (roughly, safely)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20986/12102)
- [Why is Falcon 9's shape so tall and skinny?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9273/12102)
- [If not constrained by underpasses, etc., would Falcon 9 have been less of a flying noodle?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21669/12102)
- [What determines rocket height/width?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33706/12102)
- [Smallest orbital rocket by diameter?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48183/12102) (currently unanswered, could be [this one](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22471/12102))
- [Smallest orbital rockets by height?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48148/12102)

are well and good, but after seeing the Scout D-1 in the excellent Curious Droid video [Black Arrow : The Lipstick Rocket - A Very British Space Program](https://youtu.be/FHBGAyIU8Hw?t=573) at around `09:33` (screen shot below) where it looks as thin and tall as the metal towers holding the lightning wires around the launch site I wondered if this is in fact the highest aspect ratio (height/width) or most "noodle-like" orbital launch vehicle ever.

**Question:** What is/was the most noodle-like orbital launch vehicle ever? Which one has/had the highest aspect ratio? Don't including fins, strap-ons or fairings, just the rocket body diameter. If it's modulated along the length, feel free to take some length-averaged mean diameter if necessary.

[image: screenshot from the excellent Curious Droid video Black Arrow : The Lipstick Rocket - A Very British Space Program https://youtu.be/FHBGAyIU8Hw]

---

From [If not constrained by underpasses, etc., would Falcon 9 have been less of a flying noodle?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21669/12102) illustrating that rockets can be so long and narrow that they can bend and flex in the wind!

[image: noodle-like Falcon 9 on the launch pad]

Comment: But are there lasagna, macaroni, or rotini shaped rockets?

Comment: @DrSheldon I've asked for the highest aspect ratio, right there in the title. How would you define it for those geometries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For simplicity, I will go with the ratio of height to largest cylindrical diameter. That should be an okay definition of "noodly".

This is the result of going through all the all-solid orbital launchers I could find, since none of the liquid ones were even close.

---

To start out, let's check your Scout-D.1 suspicion:
[Scout D-1](http://www.astronautix.com/s/scoutd-1.html): 25m : 1.14m = 21.93,  as a starting point.

But there were many versions of the Scout, and going through all of them, the following ones were more "noodly" than the D-1:

- [Blue Scout II](http://www.astronautix.com/b/bluescoutii.html): 24m : 1.02m = 23.52
- [Scout B](http://www.astronautix.com/s/scoutb.html): 25m: 1.01m = 24.75
- [Scout X-1](http://www.astronautix.com/s/scoutx-1.html): 25m: 1.01m = 24.75
- [Scout X-2](http://www.astronautix.com/s/scoutx-2.html): 25m: 1.01m = 24.75
- [Scout X-3](http://www.astronautix.com/s/scoutx-3.html): 24m : 1.02m = 23.76
- [Scout X-4](http://www.astronautix.com/s/scoutx-4.html): 25m: 1.01m = 24.75

I couldn't find anything better, but here's a selection of others:

Even with their noodly reputation, none of the Falcons are above 20:1

[SLV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_Launch_Vehicle) is pretty noodly, but 22m : 1m = 22 isn't good enough to beat the scouts.
[ASLV](http://www.astronautix.com/a/aslv.html): 23.5 m : 1m = 23.5, but that may or may not count as it had boosters.

[Lambda 3](http://www.astronautix.com/l/lambda3.html) 17.4m : 0.74m = 23.51, very close.

[image: danger noodle]

Scout X-2

Comment: Excellent! fyi I've just asked [Why can solid rockets be both the skinniest and most spherical launch vehicles while liquid fuel rockets have a more limited range of aspect ratios?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/52479/12102) and cited your answer as "Evidence of solid rocket launch vehicle 'noodlicity'".

Comment: [In mid-May, LandSpace showed pictures of the rocket’s 3,700-kilometer journey through China to the pad. This transport is also why the common diameter of Chinese rockets, including ZhuQue-2, is about 3.5 meters. Anything bigger than that would limit the rocket’s ability to be transported on roads and trains.](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2023/07/zhuque-2-launch2/) While also limited in diameter by domestic transportation realities, at about 14 it's not very noodly at all.